# Got undefined when try to get the value of input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When clicking on input element instead of it's value I'm getting `undefined`,
this is what I am trying:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".card_click").click(function() {
        var slug = $(this).closest("div.skill").find("input[type='hidden']").val();
        console.log(slug);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col s6  cardboard">
    <div class=" card card_click">

        <div class="content">
            <img src='img/tools_1.png' width='30' height='30'>
            <div class="count-to">php</div>
        </div>
        <div class="skill">
            <input type="hidden" name="php" value="php" class="skill_selected">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="col s6  cardboard">
    <div class=" card creport card_click">
        <div class="content">
            <img src='img/tools_2.png' width='30' height='30'>
            <div class=" count-to">python</div>
        </div>
        <div class="skill">
            <input type="hidden" name="python" value="python" class="skill_selected">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="col s6  cardboard">
    <div class=" card creport card_click">
        <div class="content">
            <img src='img/tools_2.png' width='30' height='30'>
            <div class=" count-to">react</div>
        </div>
        <div class="skill">
            <input type="hidden" name="react" value="react" class="skill_selected">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I need to be able to obtain the value of an input element inside each div with class `card_click` with the div's `click()` event listener.

Comment: change `$(this).closest("div.skill").find("input[type='hidden']").val()` to `$(this).find(".skill input[type='hidden']").val();`

Comment: its working ,thanks

Comment: code-droid, always make a snippet so we can test here.

Comment: @Swati I guess you should provide a quick answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: @Ivan86 no need to add answer it was just a typo so . I have already flagged this question as typo :)

Comment: @Swati Alright, then I'll flag it as well :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".card_click").click(function() {
        var slug = $(this).find("div.skill input[type='hidden']").val();
        console.log(slug);
    });
});
```

> The .closest() selector traverses up the DOM to find the parent that
> matches the conditions.
>
> The .find() selector traverses down the DOM where the event occurred,
> that matches the conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following variants

```js
//Using jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".card_click").click(function(currentCard) {
        var inputElem = currentCard.find("input");
        alert(inputElem.val());
    });
});

//Using plain javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".card_click").click(function(currentCard) {
        var inputElem = currentCard[0].querySelector("input");
        alert(inputElem.value);
    });
});
```